# Change (not convert) minutes into hours in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I have html output with time durations arranged in columns. The formatting varies depending on the length of the duration, and Excel is not interpreting the formatting correctly. For instance:

Ninety minutes is displayed as 1:30:00, Excel sees it as h:mm:ss

Fifteen minutes is displayed as 15:00, but Excel sees it as h:mm.

If I change the format to h:mm:ss, it becomes 15:00:00. I can manually change the data to force it to 00:15:00.

Is there an easy way to make Excel interpret the right-most numbers as always seconds?

Failing that, is there an easy way to change the data so it is all consistent?

Additional detail in response to questions below:

I only seem to have problems with the minutes only data. I'd like it all to be there correctly as h:mm:ss.

Unfortunately, I have no control over how the HTML output is formatted. I have tried copying it to a text editor first to strip out any lingering HTML, but the same thing happens.

Comment: It think you would need to ensure your HTML format is consistent; or get the data into an Excel cell as text.  Another option might be a VBA macro which could read the text value of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the "symptom" this shouldn't be impossible.. Citing :

> 1:30:00, Excel sees it as h:mm:ss

and

> I change the format to h:mm:ss, it becomes 15:00:00. I can manually change the data to force it to 00:15:00.

I have a 2 way of simple remedy..

1. Settle this during the text-to-column conversion.
2. Use conditional time data write with you current situation.

I cannot verify since no info of the url/sample file/data was shared.. hope you can share the results and benefit others too. (:

**Method1**

When pasting into excel.. during the text-to-column conversion.. use ":" as the delimiter..

then you'll end up with a 2-column-data or 3-column-data.. 
for 2-column-data (say.. A1&B1) ..

```
=time(0,A1,B1)
```

and for 3-column-data

```
=time(A1,B1,C1)
```

p/s : I think this is the closest to your "interpret the right-most numbers as always seconds?" solution..

**Method2**

Since [ 15:00 -->  h:mm ] and [ 1:30:00 --> h:mm:ss ] in your current situation, just  re-manipulate it and produce new 'real' data.

Assuming this h:mm & h:mm:ss data is in column A, add a column.. put in

```
=IF(HOUR(A1)<1,A1,TIME(0,HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1)))
```

will do just fine..

Hope it solves.. ( :